# PHP & SQL issue: Need to echo all results possible when it doesn't return some fields

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to change this sql statement to return results it does find? Basically right now `orderprc.item_no` and `orderprc.cust_no` do not always exist in the table. So if they don't my query does not return anything.

What I want to do when they don't exist is echo everything it does find, but just leave the rest blank. I am echoing these inside a table. Any suggestions? Let me know if you need more info.

```
SELECT 
    ordernumber.ord_num, 
    lineitem.item_no, 
    lineitem.item_desc_1,
    ordernumber.cus_no, 
    lineitem.unit_price, 
    cic.sman, 
    orderprc.description
FROM ordernumber JOIN lineitem
ON ordernumber.ord_num = lineitem.ord_num
JOIN cicmpy ON ordernumber.cus_no = cic.debcode
JOIN orderprc ON ordernumber.cus_no = orderprc.cust_no
WHERE ordernumber.ord_num = $multi_orders
  AND orderprc.item_no = lineitem.item_no
  AND orderprc.cust_no = ordernumber.cus_no
  AND getdate() between start_dt and end_dt
```

Comment: then you'd need to explicitly allow for `or` results. `... and o.item_no = l.item_no OR l.item_no IS NULL`, or just make your joins be `left` joins

Comment: So I am needing to echo 0 or NULL for orderprc.description when there is no record in the orderprc table for item_no or cust_no, any suggestions on that? I tried using an OR o.description is NULL, but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use an OUTER JOIN (spelled out in SQL statements as either `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`) as opposed to an INNER JOIN.  When you just use the term `JOIN`, it defaults to an INNER JOIN.

In your example, the SQL statement would look like:

```
SELECT ordernumber.ord_num, lineitem.item_no, lineitem.item_desc_1,
    ordernumber.cus_no, lineitem.unit_price, cic.sman, orderprc.description
FROM ordernumber 
    JOIN lineitem ON ordernumber.ord_num = lineitem.ord_num
        JOIN cicmpy ON ordernumber.cus_no = cic.debcode
            LEFT JOIN orderprc ON ordernumber.cus_no = orderprc.cust_no
WHERE ordernumber.ord_num = $multi_orders
    AND orderprc.item_no = lineitem.item_no
    AND orderprc.cust_no = ordernumber.cus_no
    AND getdate() BETWEEN start_dt AND end_dt
```

Comment: Just a little explanation for the op: LEFT JOIN will return all records from the table to the left of the join statement, regardless if any of those records have a match in the right table. RIGHT JOIN does the inverse. INNER JOIN (or just JOIN), on the other hand, requires that both tables have a match for a result to be returned.

Comment: So orderprc.description is the record I need to return null if orderprc.item_no AND orderprc.cust_no dont have a record. Any ideas on how to do that? I tried adding or orderprc.description is null after the two and lines. but it still didnt return, I also added the left join like you mentioned.